# Java Cascading Inheritance : Anonymous Class VS Delegation or Inner Class

Tags: java, inheritance, anonymous

I was wondering if we can achieve something like this in java.

We have an interface Interface1 with an adapter Adapter, and another interface that inherit from Interface1 like below

```
public interface Interface1 {
    void doSomething();
}
public interface Interface2 extends Interface1 {
    void doOtherThing();
}

public abstract class Adapter implements Interface1 {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Nope");
    }
}
```

Then, we want to instanciate an Interface2 in a factory method relying on the Adapter

```
public class SomeWhere {

    public static Interface1 create1() {
        return new Adapter () {};
    }

    public static Interface2 create2() {
        return new Adapter & Interface2 () { //  Generic formalism, but obviously it does not compile
            public void doOtherThing() {
                System.out.println("Why me?!");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

My concrete application defines interface like MyObject (getters + methods) and MyObject.Editable (setters), most of the code in MyObject could be defined as default in interface (but I made an adapter!) as it relies on getter methods, but I have several implementations that will have different getters depending on the nature of the Object and some others will require Override but it represent less than 5 lines of code each time...

So, I'm looking for a solution which use Anonymous Class rather than
Delegation :

```
    return new Interface2 () {
        Interface1 delegate /* = new Adapter() */;
        
        public void doSomething() {
            delegate.doSomething();
        }
        public void doOtherThing() {
            System.out.println("Why me?!");
        }
        
    }
```

(Here, with more than 20 methods, code will not remain readable!)

or Inner Class :

```
    class AnotherAdapter extends Adapter implements Interface2 {...}
```

Same issue with verbosity even if it is drastically reduced compared to Delegation...

I think I already read something about this but it was for Java 8 or below, maybe some trick can do the job today (^_^)'

PS: Without anonymous class and an Inner (method) Class, I can achieve it like this

```
public class SomeWhere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create2().doOtherThing();
    }

    public static Interface2 create2() {
        class Adapter2 extends Adapter implements Interface2 {
            public void doOtherThing() {
                System.out.println("Why me?!");
            }
        }
        return new Adapter2();
    }

}
```

But it is just another kind of inner class...

Answer (score 0):

Why is `Adapter` not implementing `Interface2`?

```
public abstract class Adapter implements Interface1, Interface2 {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Nope");
    }

    // ... omitted 500 methods that are placed here to save your day
}
```

and then you can return it using

```
public class SomeWhere {

    public static Interface2 create2() {
        return new Adapter () {
    
            // Only need to provide the implementation for that single abstract method here 
            @Override
            public void doOtherThing() {
                System.out.println("Why me?!");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: If we're talking about adaptors in the sense of [the pattern of that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), it should not implement both interfaces. It should implement the Interface1 and encapsulate an Interface2

Comment: IMHO OP used the `Adapter` to save redundant "default" implementations for a lot of interface methods, similar to the Swing adapters for listeners.

Comment: You're only guessing about that. Since the class is abstract, there is no requirement that it implements anything.

Comment: Sure, but I just took that info from OP "My concrete application defines interface like MyObject (getters + methods) and MyObject.Editable (setters), most of the code in MyObject could be defined as default in interface (but I made an adapter!)" - also, I can only work with what's in the question, I usually don't speculate about stuff that's not there

Comment: The Adapter represents or encapulates or uses an instance of something 'gettable' but not 'settable' according to the MyObject and MyObject.Editable pattern, it is some kind of violation to make the Adapter implements the 'settable' aspect...
Yes, that's right, my main objective is to save code. In this case, it perfectly matches as most of methods are maths with properties. And making both adapters for gettable and settable is not practical as the setting aspect will greatly depends on the nature of what is used to complete the MyObject.Editable instance.

Comment: Sounds like a self made overengineered artificial problem to me, perhaps a changed question helps understanding what the underlying problem is, but I currently don’t